# How to manage form state with BLoC pattern?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I am currently working on a side project to learn about Rx and BLoC pattern.

I would like to manage the form state without using any `setState()`.

I already have a BLoC that manage my 'events' which are stored in a SQLite db and added after validating this form.

Do I need to create a need BLoC specifically for this UI part, and how ? Is it OK to keep a code like that ? Should I change my actual BLoC ?

You can find my current code here :

```
class _EventsAddEditScreenState extends State<EventsAddEditScreen> {
  bool hasDescription = false;
  bool hasLocation = false;  
  bool hasChecklist = false;

  DateTime eventDate;
  TextEditingController eventNameController =  new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController =  new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final eventBloc = BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context);
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: eventBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, EventsState state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildEventImage(context),
                    hasDescription ? _buildDescriptionSection(context) : _buildAddSection('description'),
                    _buildAddSection('location'),
                    _buildAddSection('checklist'),
                    //_buildDescriptionSection(context),
                  ],
                ))
              ]),
              new Positioned(
                //Place it at the top, and not use the entire screen
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: AppBar(
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.check), onPressed: () async{
                      if(this._checkAllField()){
                        String description = hasDescription ? this.descriptionController.text : null;
                        await eventBloc.dispatch(AddEvent(Event(this.eventNameController.text, this.eventDate,"balbla", description: description)));
                        print('Saving ${this.eventDate} ${eventNameController.text}');
                      }
                    },)
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //No more green
                  elevation: 0.0, //Shadow gone
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAddSection(String sectionName) {
    TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700);
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 40.0, right: 40.0, bottom: 20.0),
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          switch(sectionName){
            case('description'):{
              this.setState((){hasDescription = true;});
            }
            break;
            case('checklist'):{
              this.setState((){hasChecklist = true;});
            }
            break;
            case('location'):{
              this.setState((){hasLocation=true;});
            }
            break;
            default:{

            }
            break;
          }
        },
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 0.0),
        child: Text(
          '+ Add $sectionName',
          style: textStyle,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: These are too many questions, please be specific on what's your error or what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's solve this step by step.

Your first question:
**Do I need to create a need BLoC specifically for this UI part?**

Well this relative of your needs and your app. You can have a BLoC for each screen if needed but you can have too a single BLoC for 2 or 3 widgets, there is no rule about it. If you think that in this case is a good approach implement another BLoC for your screen because the code will be more readable, organized and scaleable you can do this or if you think that is better make only one bloc with all inside you're free to this too.

Your second question: **and how ?**

Well in your code I only see `setState` calls in `_buildAddSection` so let's change this writing a new BLoc class and handle state changes with [RxDart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart) streams.

```
class LittleBloc {
  // Note that all stream already start with an initial value. In this case, false.

  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _descriptionSubject = BehaviorSubject.seeded(false);
  Observable<bool> get hasDescription => _descriptionSubject.stream;

  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _checklistSubject = BehaviorSubject.seeded(false);
  Observable<bool> get hasChecklist => _checklistSubject.stream;

  final BehaviorSubject<bool> _locationSubject = BehaviorSubject.seeded(false);
  Observable<bool> get hasLocation => _locationSubject.stream;

  void changeDescription(final bool status) => _descriptionSubject.sink.add(status);
  void changeChecklist(final bool status) => _checklistSubject.sink.add(status);
  void changeLocation(final bool status) => _locationSubject.sink.add(status);

  dispose(){
    _descriptionSubject?.close();
    _locationSubject?.close();
    _checklistSubject?.close();
  }
}
```

Now I will use this BLoc in your widget. I will put the entire `build` method code below with the changes. Basically we'll use `StreamBuilder` to build widgets in widget tree.

```
 final LittleBloc bloc = LittleBloc(); // Our instance of bloc 
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final eventBloc = BlocProvider.of<EventsBloc>(context);
    return BlocBuilder(
      bloc: eventBloc,
      builder: (BuildContext context, EventsState state) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                    child: ListView(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildEventImage(context),
                        StreamBuilder<bool>(
                          stream: bloc.hasDescription,
                          builder: (context, snapshot){
                            hasDescription = snapshot.data; // if you want hold the value
                            if (snapshot.data)
                              return _buildDescriptionSection(context);//we got description true

                            return buildAddSection('description'); // we have description false
                          }
                        ),
                        _buildAddSection('location'),
                        _buildAddSection('checklist'),
                        //_buildDescriptionSection(context),
                      ],
                    ),
                ),
              ]
              ),
              new Positioned(
                //Place it at the top, and not use the entire screen
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: AppBar(
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.check), 
                      onPressed: () async{
                        if(this._checkAllField()){
                          String description = hasDescription ? this.descriptionController.text : null;
                          await eventBloc.dispatch(AddEvent(Event(this.eventNameController.text, this.eventDate,"balbla", description: description)));
                          print('Saving ${this.eventDate} ${eventNameController.text}');
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent, //No more green
                  elevation: 0.0, //Shadow gone
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And no more `setState` calls in your `_buildAddSection`. Just need change a `switch` statement. The `changes...`calls will update the streams in BLoc class and this will make a rebuild of the widget that is listening the stream.

```
switch(sectionName){
  case('description'):
    bloc.changeDescription(true);
    break;

  case('checklist'):
    bloc.changeChecklist(true);
    break;

  case('location'):
    bloc.changeLocation(true);
    break;

  default:
    // you better do something here!
    break;
}
```

And don't forgot to call `bloc.dispose()` inside inside WidgetState `dispose` method.

Comment: Wow awesome answer, thank you so much, i've been missing something about the BLoC pattern and it's now a way much clearer !